# Fetch and delete redis data using bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, redis, redis-cli

I have created a bat file for deleting specific data from Redis DB. I have follwing code

```
title:Redis Service
@echo off
cls
ECHO "Redis cache clearing started"
ECHO "fetching started method 1"
redis-cli -h 192.134.56.67 -p 6379 -a MyPassword keys "My.Key.*"
ECHO "fetching started method 2"
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`redis-cli -h 192.134.56.67 -p 6379 -a MyPassword keys "My.Key.*"`) DO (
SET var=%%F
)
ECHO "fetching completed"
ECHO %var%
ECHO "deletion started"
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`redis-cli -h 192.134.56.67 -p 6379 -a MyPassword del %var%`) DO (
SET var2=%%F
)
ECHO %var2%
ECHO "deletion completed"
pause
```

I got Output like this

```
"Redis cache clearing started"
"fetching started method 2"
 1) "My.Key.2554"
 2) "My.Key.280017"
 3) "My.Key.224"
 4) "My.Key.23730"
 5) "My.Key.2072545"

"fetching completed"
"fetching started method 2"
My.Key.2072545
"deletion started"
1
"deletion completed"
```

I need to delete whole data from the Redis command output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each run of the first loop `set`'s variable `var` with a new value, so each iteration of the loop will re-assign the new value to `var`. So by the time you exit that loop, `var` has only one value which in this case is `My.Key.20725545` Instead, use one loop, do not assign variables as you would then need `delayedexpansion`. So you would need something like this rather. **Note!!** I do not have `redis` so I cannot test this result, it is merely an example of how it should probably be:

```
@echo off & cls
title :Redis Service
echo "Redis cache clearing started"
for /F "tokens=*" %%f IN ('redis-cli -h 192.134.56.67 -p 6379 -a MyPassword keys "My.Key.*"') do (
 echo "%%~f"
 redis-cli -h 192.134.56.67 -p 6379 -a MyPassword del "%%~f"
)
echo deletion completed
```

Comment: this is taking a long time. How to use scan instead of keys in above code

Comment: ok, that is the new question you asked, I left a comment there, please see it.